# Having problems with Javascript Else If statement in Node Red

Tags: javascript, if-statement, node-red

I have been fighting this problem all day. Heres a snippet of my code, 5 lines down in the `else if` is where things get screwy. I am also new to Javascript so that may be the reason I am unable to spot the mistake, but from what I have seen elsewhere, this code should work. Also the comments on lines 5 and 6 are swapped.

```
if (msg.payload.License_Plate !== null) {
    // This portion checks for a valid number plate
    if (readlpr == dblpr); {        // we have a direct match, open the gate
        opengate = 1;               // will send open signal to gpio
    } else if(readlpr !== null); {     // from here on, we are checking for a partial plate match
        validdigits = 0;  // make sure we have data before continuing, as may be a rfid match
        {
        if (!context.count); {   // check to see if counter already used, if not initialise it
            context.count = 0;
```

**Image of error message**

[image]

Comment: Can you update your code with valid syntax? (and use 4 spaces instead of ticks for formatting)

Comment: Hi raj, if you found my answer answered your question please upvote and/or accept. If you still have questions please let me know and I'd be glad to help out where I can.

Comment: @raj Hi raj, thanks for commenting on my answer. However I only get reputation for an upvote on my answer and a bonus would be accepting it since it was the solution. You can read more about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few errors:

```
if (readlpr == dblpr); {
...
} else if(readlpr !== null); {
...
if (!context.count); {
```

And also an extra opening-brace.

These shouldn't have a semi colon on the end:

```
if (readlpr == dblpr) {
...
} else if(readlpr !== null) {
...
if (!context.count) {
```

In the end it should look something like this:

```
if (msg.payload.License_Plate !== null) {
    if (readlpr == dblpr) {
        opengate = 1;
    } else if(readlpr !== null) {
        validdigits = 0;
    //  { <!-- Remove this as well, it's an extra brace
        if (!context.count) {
            context.count = 0;
```